# imagebutton height and width

Tags: android, android-layout, imagebutton

I have a clasical android problem, butI can't solve it.

I have a imageButton, but it is deformed, the height is bigger than it should be, this is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

      <!-- other content -->
    
     </LinearLayout>
     
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
     
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/sabadell_but"
            android:background="@drawable/banner_sabadell"
            android:contentDescription="@string/infoDesc"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
       </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

this is what I should see:

[image]

And this is what i see:

[image]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you use your image as a background
you should use it as a scource:

```
android:src="@drawable/banner_sabadell"
```

and if you'll got some problems with the size for different screens you'll got to play with an  scale_type attribute

```
 android:scaleType="fitXY" /// or some others
```

and it will be better for you to make a 9patch image from your banner..
yeap, shure ... you got to make this:

```
android:background="#00000000"
```

or

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: I need it as background because if not, what I see is a button with a image, do it exist another way to avoid this effect?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `scaleType = "fitCentre"`. Before that set height width `wrap_content`

[This link](http://etcodehome.blogspot.ru/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html) would also help you to identify the scale type you want to use.